# How to change the red container after pressing the continue button? Only red container is needed to be changed

Tags: java, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image: 1]

How to change the red conatiner after pressing the continue button? In place of red container a new container should be formed having text field as phone number and other things should be as it is. Only red container is needs to be changed.

Comment: Image is in the link above --  enter image description here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please share your code with us. It's not possible to help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is the same thing the widget [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) does.
See this [tutorial](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-16-stepper-485ad8d1a248)

and here is another way of doing the same thing:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int page = 0;
  final int maxPages = 3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          if(page == 0)
            Text("This is view 1"),
          if(page == 1)
            Text("This is view 2"),
          if(page == 2)
            Text("This is view 3"),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Continue"),
            onPressed: (){
              if(page < maxPages){
                setState(() {
                 page++; 
                });
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a boolean value.
example

```
  bool value = false;
    Column(children: <Widgets>[
         contains(),
         RaisedButton(child: Text("Continue"), 
           onPresssed: (){
             setState((){
                value = true;
               });
            }),
 ])
    Widget contains(){
     if(value == true){
      return Container(//the Container after Continue BUtton Pressed );
  }

   else{
    return Container(
     //The Red Container
   );
  }
}
```